# Git merge mistake

Tags: git, gitlab, devops

`Hello all,

I am newbie in git. I am working on a project and interacting with git thoroughly, and did a blunder today.
I merged two branches in this way:
branch_01 >> branch_02 then,
branch_02 >> branch_01

Active branch on server is branch_02

and lost all commits between 5 NOV 2022 to today date from branch_02. Now branch_01 has all 23 commits which is suppose to be on branch_02.

PREVIOUSLY:
I merged two branches in this way:
branch_01 >> branch_02 then,
branch_02 >> branch_01
I tried:
branch_01 >> branch_02

but didn't get my commit back. `

Answer (score 4):

`git reflog` to the rescue. It will give you the "backend" of what happened with your branch. You'll get a log looking sth like

```
b5cc58d (HEAD -> main, view-pagination) HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from typeorm-module to main
2703297 (typeorm-module) HEAD@{1}: commit: WIP some mess
b5cc58d (HEAD -> main, view-pagination) HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from main to typeorm-module
b5cc58d (HEAD -> main, view-pagination) HEAD@{3}: merge view-pagination: Fast-forward
2e4e719 HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from view-pagination to main
```

On that list, find the moment "before it all went to heck", and do hard reset:

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{4}
```

On both branches.

Then have a cup of tea and do the merging the way you intended in the first place.